# How to go on administration page in NopCommerce CMS

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce

I have logged in using the information provided during installation by using the normal login page but it says

```
Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.
The credentials provided are incorrect
```

From where i can go to administrator page link???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check the `[Customer]` table in your database. check the user name or email id that are correct or not...

If they are correct then use forgot password link at the login page.

Might be your login name or password was wrong....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset the password with through SQL in **Customer** Table, please make sure you make PasswordSalt as Null. After resetting the password. Refresh your page and enter password and after you logged in then you can see a link to **Administration** on top

Answer (score 0):

Open the table Customer in SQL database and find the Built-in system user whose `email = "builtin@search_engine_record.com"`.
The Id is 7 in nopCommerce 4.0.
By default this user is active.
Set it `Active = False`.
Login and you will see the Administrator Link at the top of the page.

Comment: For this that user must have assign with Admin role and user start with builtin... is represent it is guest user and he don't have access for admin area.